# How to pass more data autocomplete ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using [jQueryUI autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/).

> This is my data of a product with its respective brand details
>   (Laravel relationship/SQL join)

```
[
  {
    "id": 2, <--------- product.id
    "name": "iphone", <--------- product.name
    "created_at": "2017-02-08 06:12:34",
    "updated_at": "2017-02-08 06:12:34",
    "user_id": 1,
    "brand_id": 1,
    "ms_url": "google.com",
    "gravity": 1.03,
    "example_id": null,
    "relevance": 210,
    "brand": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "apple",<--------- product.brand.name
      "created_at": "2017-02-08 03:00:49",
      "updated_at": "2017-02-08 03:00:49",
      "user_id": 1,
      "abbreviation": "AP",
      "visible": 1
    }
  }
]
```

> This is the ajax part of autocomplete() options. I wanted it to
>   fill the input with the brand and then the product name.

```
source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/find",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        term: request.term
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error: ' + xhr.responseText);
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('data: ' + data.brand.name + ' - ' + data.name);
        //Outputs: apple - iphone
        response($.map(data, function(product) {
          return {
            label: product.brand.name + " " + product.name,
            value: product.brand.name + " - " + product.name
          };
        }))
      }
    });
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
    console.log(ui);
    //only conains product.brand.name & product.name, I need product.id 

    //  $(this).data('prod-id', ui.id);

  }
```

**Question:** How can I also pass the `product.id` so I can add it to a data attribute on my input? I have dynamically added inputs and I wish to check the product id on the backend before submitting to the database rather than checking the input value.

Current output of input

```
<input type="text" class="ui-autocomplete-input" data-prod-id="" value="apple - iphone">
```

Desired output of input

```
<input type="text" class="ui-autocomplete-input" data-prod-id="2" value="apple - iphone">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take different value of "value" and "label" key then assign value at time of select event.

Example:

```
source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/find",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        term: request.term
      },
      error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('Error: ' + xhr.responseText);
      },
      success: function(data) {
        console.log('data: ' + data.brand.name + ' - ' + data.name);
        //Outputs: apple - iphone
        response($.map(data, function(product) {
          return {
            label: product.brand.name + " - " + product.name,
            value: product.id //<---------- assign product id
          };
        }))
      }
    });
  },
  select: function(event, ui) {
     $(this).val(ui.item.label); //<----------- assign value of lable

     $(this).attr('data-prod-id', ui.item.value); //<------data-prod-id
     return false; //<------------ to prevent from assign original value

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with this approach. It seems that you have to specify at least **either** a label, or a value. So as long as you set one of either, you can add extra necessary items into the array.

```
response($.map(data, function(product) {
  return {
    id: product.id,
    title: product.brand.name + " - " + product.name,
    value: product.brand.name + "  " + product.name
  };
}))
```